# Android how to capture touch points location on regular time interval

Tags: android, input, timer, touch

How to capture touch points location on regular time interval only when touch even is triggered. That is time interval is trigged only after touch event is trigged and time interval terminated when touch event is terminates.

Right now I have written code to capture touch points by referring android developer document. Please advice how to modify the code to capture touch location in regulate time interval.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

// get pointer index from the event object
int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();

// get pointer ID
int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);

// get masked (not specific to a pointer) action
int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();

switch (maskedAction) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        {
            // We have a new pointer. Lets add it to the list of pointers
            PointF f = new PointF();
            f.x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
            f.y = event.getY(pointerIndex);
            // Do something
            break;
        }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        { // a pointer was moved
            for (int size = event.getPointerCount(), i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                PointF f = new PointF();
                f.x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
                f.y = event.getY(pointerIndex);
                // Do something
            }
            break;
        }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:{
       // trigger to stop the time interval 
    }
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a TimerTask & set a flag when timer task meets a particular time , like

```
        timer = new Timer();
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {

                 grabThePosition=true;

                }
            }, 0, samplingInterval);
        }
```

In `onTouchEvent` check the flag & get the x,y positions then reset the flag .

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want to check the current time (either system or something like Joda Time) at the moment ACTION_POINTER_DOWN triggers and store it as pressed time value. On ACTION_MOVE, if the current time - pressed time == time gap, write down the point. At that point reinitialize the pressed time var to the current time and repeat.